# sifr links color not changing

Tags: sifr

I've tried to replace the styles of link on my site, and it seems like the font face is replaced successfully, but it's not taking in the color and text-decoration. Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var archermed = {src: 'archermed.swf'}; sIFR.activate(archermed);sIFR.replace(archermed, {selector: '.CollectionTopTabHdr',css: '.sIFR-root {font-size:14px; color:#663399; text-decoration; font-weight:normal; margin:0;} a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {color:#663399; text-decoration:none;}',wmode: 'transparent'});</script>
```

here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="CollectionTopTabHdr"><a href="#">LINK</a></div>
```

Thanks in advance!
18fis

Comment: I know you're asking about something else, but I'd suggest you try out cufón: http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon

Answer (score 0):

I found out from another question that I need to separate out the link states in css, so here is what I did, and it works now!:

```
sIFR.replace(archerbold, {selector: '.sifrHeader',css: ['.sIFR-root { font-size:14px; color: #663399;}','a { text-decoration: none; color: #663399; }','a:link { color: #663399; }','a:hover { color: #663399; }','a:active {color:#663399;}'],offsetTop: -1, tuneHeight: 0,wmode: 'transparent', forceSingleLine: true});
```